# Java swing animation issue

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a code for animation in java swing..I am having problems when i run it..The program is not exactly running as it is not displaying continuously but after few seconds..It does not show the transition but the starting and final position..Please provide the remedial actions in the code..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
class Abc 
{
    int x=0,y=0;
    JButton button;
    JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Abc a = new Abc();
        a.go();
    } // main method ends
    void go()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        button = new JButton("Click Me!");
        button.addActionListener(new hpe());
        mydraw dr = new mydraw();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,dr);
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } // go method ends
    class hpe implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            button.setText("Changed!");
            for(int i=0;i<130;i++)
            {
                x = x + 1;
                y = y + 1;
                frame.repaint();
                try
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(50);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                } // catch ends
            } // for loop ends
        } // actionPerformed method ends
    } // class hpe ends
    class mydraw extends JPanel
    {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x,y,40,40);
        } // paintComponent method ends
    } // class mydraw ends
} // class Abc ends
```

Comment: Is the code suppose to perform animations when you click the button?

Comment: Yes sir.It is supposed to animate after click on the button but it is not exactly working as i want it to.

Comment: My guess is that `Thread.currentThread().sleep(50);` prevents thread responsible for handling Swing from doing *anything* for 50ms, including repainting action. It would be better to have some other thread change your x,y values and call repaint every 50ms. Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: No guessing needed -- you're putting the Swing event thread to sleep. Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

Comment: Other issues -- don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g);` within your JPanel's paintComponent override method, call it first to allow the JPanel to do "house-keeping" painting and to not break the painting chain. Also learn and follow [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: Your question has been closed as a duplicate, but since you've been given bad advice by @Ryan with incorrect code, let me correct this. Please check out a correct answer, one that uses a Swing Timer [here](https://pastebin.com/snxPq2Ud).